# XML Table to RDBMS

Tags: sql, oracle, xml-parsing

I am converting XML table to RDBMS but it is taking 3 hours for 300K records and 30 columns. My query looks like below:

```
SELECT
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c202)[1]') AS VARCHAR2 (15))
        AS RECORD_STATUS,
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c203)[1]') AS VARCHAR2 (15))
        AS CURR_NO,
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c204)[1]') AS VARCHAR2 (15))
        AS INPUTTER,
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c205)[1]') AS VARCHAR2 (15))
        AS DATE_TIME,
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c206)[1]') AS VARCHAR2 (15))
        AS AUTHORISER,
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c207)[1]') AS VARCHAR2 (15))
        AS CO_CODE   ,
     CAST (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLRECORD, '(/row/c210)[1]') AS NUMBER)
        AS AUDIT_DATE_TIME
FROM TABLE@DBLINK
```

Comment: I imagine you can use things like XMLTable but without table structures, sample data and expected results it's rather hard to tell.  The database link might not be helping too.

Comment: Why not use python for parsing and write to the db?

Comment: DB Link """WOW""", I never preferred that, you are performing 1+1 twice over thousand of matric transaction (reduce the overhead of db link)

Comment: That's 3 hours for nearly a million XML field queries over a database link. That's about 5000 a minute, or 80 a second. Sounds about right to me.

Comment: Alex XML Table is better than  EXTRACTVALUE  but still is taking more time than what I expect